# Google Cloud Platform Postman Only Calls Function Through Main Google Account And Not Service Account

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, postman, service-accounts

I made a service account in GCP designed to run a cloud function. This is the service account, complete with json keys that I downloaded.
[image]

Then I made this cloud function. It is the default python 3.9 function that simply prints out the `message` you send it or if there is no `message`, it just prints "Hello World!"
[image]

I set it up with an HTTP trigger requiring authentication with the service account I just created `second_try` as the runtime service account for the cloud function. See the permissions for the cloud function below:
[image]

When I ran `Test function`, it worked even though I never referenced my service account credntials.
[image]

I tested the curl command in postman:

```
curl -m 70 -X POST https://us-central1-<MY PROJECT NAME>.cloudfunctions.net/func_two_hg \
-H "Authorization:bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{}'
```

And it worked even though I'm not referencing my service account credentials which is confusing...

Even more confusing, when I try to reference the service account credentials and therefore run the function through the service account, it gives a 401 error, citing `Your client does not have permission to the requested URL`. This is the curl command that incorporated the service account credentials:

```
curl -m 70 -X POST https://us-central1-<MY PROJECT NAME>.cloudfunctions.net/func_two_hg \
-H "Authorization:bearer $(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{}'
```

And this is the error:
[image]

What is the problem, and why won't it run with the service account credentials? And how do I make this function only run-able through the service account?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your question with embedded images. I encourage you to use `gcloud` to list/describe resources. You can then embed text in your question(s) and make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: When you run the Cloud Function test in the browser, you're authenticating as the user that's logged in to Cloud Console (in the browser). This is probably your user account and it's probably a project owner/editor and it therefore has permission to invoke the function

Comment: When you run the `curl` command using the `Bearer` value `gcloud auth print-identity-token`, you're authenticating as the user that's authenticated (default) to `gcloud` (via `gcloud auth login`) and probably (!) the same user as your authenticated in the browser. Thus, the same explanation.

Comment: The command `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` does not do what you want it to do. `gcloud` does not leverage `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` so using the environment variable here does nothing. `gcloud auth application-default` is discourage. What it does is uses your user account (again) to authenticate as a Service Account. So, you're using the same credentials again (3rd time) but this time getting an access token (rather than identity token) and so it fails.

Comment: If you've configured everything correctly, you should `https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account` to enable the Service Account. Then you can `gcloud auth print-identity-token --account=${ACCOUNT}` where `ACCOUNT` is the Service Account email to get an identity token that should authenticate you to the Cloud Function.

Comment: This worked! Specifically activating the service account worked. I ran `gcloud auth activate-service-account second-try@<MY PROJECT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/path/to/credentials.json` and then running the curl command with the output of `gcloud auth print-identity-token --account=second-try@<MY PROJECT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as the bearer token works! I guess I just needed to activate the service account. Thanks! You can put this as a solution and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've configured everything correctly, you should:

1. [gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) to enable the Service Account.
2. Then you can `gcloud auth print-identity-token --account=${ACCOUNT}` where `ACCOUNT` is the Service Account email to get an identity token that should authenticate you to the Cloud Function.